Issue with Screenshot Discrepancies Across Different Windows Versions
We are experiencing an issue with our UI test cases after updating Canvas from version 2.10.2 to 2.11.2. When running tests on Windows Server 2019, the UI snapshots generated do not match those generated on local systems like Windows 10 or 11.
Specifically, when running the same tests on Windows 10 or 11, we observe inconsistencies in text rendering on the UI, which we capture via Canvas. These differences are notable as yellow pixels appearing below the fonts.
We have attempted several workarounds, including disabling anti-aliasing and adjusting font quality by modifying the Canvas context, but these efforts have not resolved the issue.
It seems the problem may stem from differences in UI rendering or text measurement across different Windows versions. We would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential Windows configuration changes that might help us address this inconsistency.
Example of Differences
screenshot mismatch example 1
screenshot mismatch example 2
Additional Information
We are using Node version 20.18.0, however when tried on Node 18.20.0 also we faced similar issues i.e. discrepancies between UI rendered on Windows 11 vs Windows server 2019. Apparently Canvas 2.11.2 is minimum recommended version of Canvas for Node 20 LTS version. This issue started occurring after upgrading to Node 20.18.0 and Canvas 2.11.2. Previously, with Node 18.20.0 and Canvas 2.10.2, the tests were passing consistently across different Windows OS versions.
Any help, guidance, or comments on this issue would be highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Isn't canvas using the GPU for rendering? Servers and client systems usually have different GPU and drivers.
